# Hiding a html table with knockout data-bind

Tags: knockout.js

I know we can hide a table if no data is present like this: **visible: Vehicles().length>0**

```
<table data-bind="visible: Vehicles().length>0">
    <thead><tr><th>Brand</th><th>Model</th><th>Registration</th><th></th></tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Vehicles">
        <tr data-bind="click: $root.goToVehicle">
            <td data-bind="text: Brand"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Model"></td>
        </tr>     
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The Vehicles is an observable object.

Now I have another scenario:

```
<table data-bind="with: chosenCategoryData">
    <thead><tr><th>Brand</th><th>Model</th><th>Registration</th><th></th></tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Vehicles">
        <tr data-bind="click: $root.goToVehicle">
            <td data-bind="text: Brand"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Model"></td>
        </tr>     
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, my Vehicles object which contains my data to fill the html table is contained in another object (observable) named chosenCategoryData.

I try to hide the table with `visible: Vehicles().length>0` but I got an error, maybe because Vehicles is not observable.

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, you can't use `with` and `visible` in the same `data-bind`. You can wrap it in another `<div>`

```
<div data-bind="with: chosenCategoryData">
    <table data-bind="visible: Vehicles.length">...</table>
</div>
```

or use the virtual syntax:

```
<!-- ko with: chosenCategoryData -->
<table data-bind="visible: Vehicles.length">
<!-- /ko -->
```

Take a look as this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LaDgd/2/). Use `Vehicles()` if that is an `observableArray`.

Comment: I try as you suggested but it doesn't work. I think the reason is that my Vehicles object is contained in the other object chosenCategoryData.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the example and added a live example via jsfiddle.

Comment: Thank you. Your help was precious.